# WKWebView fails to load resource

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

In our app we are using WKWebView to upload an image and save it in server. This works fine in Safari, but it doesnt work in the WkWebView.

```
    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) configuration:theConfiguration];
    _webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    _webView.UIDelegate = self;

    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://lo---url...new"];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [_webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

After the image is attached by imagePickerController, when I try to hit save button, the safari debugger shows an error:

> Failed to load resource. Network connection was lost.

Nothing is caught in `-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error`. This method is not called .

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Do you get more information when implementing the navigationDelegate and checking out the error received in `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError)`

Comment: @Paul.s no. I do not get any error  info!

Comment: Did the failure delegate method get called at all?

Comment: @Paul.s no. It was not called . I see the error in the safari debugger console.

Comment: Did you assign the delegate correctly?

Comment: Yes. DidFinishNavigation gets called correctly. It's just the error method doesnt get called. I can see that error only in the safari debugger.

Comment: @Paul.s I am resetting the cache in viewDidDisappear. So, when imagepicker controller class appear, the webview is resetting.This causes the error.